# Pandas - row selection with column operation & .loc[]

Tags: pandas, pandas-loc

I have been practicing with pandas and have the following problem. I have been practicing with an Olympic medal data set where the countries are listed in one column, and the medals in subsequent columns.

As part of a QC check, I wanted to write a line of code that checks that the sum of the gold (01 !), silver (02 !) and bronze (03 !) medals is equal to the value in the 'total' column. I have tried this a number of ways, including .apply with the function below, and also with .loc[] (see code below). However, I keep on getting errors back. Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

To expand, the idea of the code would be to select all rows where the sum is correct, and exclude those which are not. I have shown two of the methods I have tried below.

I am new to python and coding in general so apologies if my question is not clear enough.

Many thanks

Luke

```
df = pd.DataFrame({Country: ['Afghanistan', 'Algeria', 'Argentina'],        
01 !: [0, 0, 1],
02 !: [5, 2, 8],
03 !: [18, 24, 28],
Total: [23, 26, 38]})

def medal_sum_check(gold, silver, bronze, total):
    if gold + silver + bronze == total:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df2 = df.loc[df.apply(medal_sum_check(df.iloc[1], df.iloc[2], df.iloc[3], df.iloc[4]))]

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

or

```
df2 = df.loc[(df.iloc[1] + df.iloc[2] + df.iloc[3] == df.iloc[4])]

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: `01 !` is not a valid key. is it supposed to be a string instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly add do the conditional check on the entire column in pandas. Here is a demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ['Afghanistan', 'Algeria', 'Argentina'],        
"01 !": [0, 0, 1],
"02 !": [5, 2, 8],
"03 !": [18, 24, 28],
"Total": [23, 26, 38]})

print(df["01 !"] + df["02 !"] + df["03 !"] == df["Total"])
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
```

You can also add the check output as a new column in your data frame by doing this:

```
df["check"] = df["01 !"] + df["02 !"] + df["03 !"] == df["Total"]
```

Then your DataFrame will look like this:

```
       Country  01 !  02 !  03 !  Total  check
0  Afghanistan     0     5    18     23   True
1      Algeria     0     2    24     26   True
2    Argentina     1     8    28     38  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need that weird column names. The following code will do what you are trying to do.

```
Country =  ['Afghanistan', 'Algeria', 'Argentina']
a =  [0, 0, 1]
b = [5, 2, 8]
c = [18, 24, 28]
Total =  [23, 26, 38]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Country,a,b,c,Total)),columns=["country","gold","silver","bronze","total"])

print(df["gold"]+df["silver"]+df["bronze"]==df["total"])
```

And output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

In your case, please change the column names first.